# How to find the number of all the possible ordered trees with n edges and k leaves?

Tags: combinatorics, trees

We know that a tree with n edges have n+1 nodes.So if $|B_{n+1}|$ is the number of all possible ordered trees with n+1 nodes then its true that $C_{n+1} = |B_{n+1}|$ where $C$ is the Catalan number.Let it be $|L_k|$ the number of all possible ordered trees with n+1 nodes and k leaves and Its true that 
$|B_{n+1}| = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}|L_i|$.

---

If my thinking is correct how can I continue or if you have a better idea please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a contribution using basic complex variables.

We  will compute  the number  of  trees on  $n$ nodes  and having  $q$
leaves.

The  combinatorial class equation  for ordered  rooted trees with leaves marked is
$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{Z}\times \mathcal{U}
+ \mathcal{Z} \times \textsc{SEQ}_{\ge 1}(\mathcal{T})
\quad\text{or}\quad
\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{Z}\times\mathcal{U}
+ \mathcal{Z} \times \sum_{p\ge 1} \mathcal{T}^p.$$

This yields the functional equation for the generating function $T(z)$
$$T(z) = zu + z\frac{T(z)}{1-T(z)}$$
or $$z = \frac{T(z)}{u+T(z)/(1-T(z))}
= \frac{T(z)(1-T(z))}{T(z)+u(1-T(z))}.$$

Note that  leaves in addition to  being marked as such  also carry the
node marker so that the total  number of nodes includes the leaves. If
this is not  desired subtract the number of leaves  from the number of
nodes to get the count of genuine internal nodes.

Starting the computation we seek

$$T_n(u) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\gamma} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} T(z) \; dz.$$
and will compute this by Lagrange inversion.

Put $w=T(z)$ so that
$$dz = 
\left(\frac{1-2w}{w+u(1-w)}
- \frac{w(1-w)}{(w+u(1-w))^2} (1-u) \right) dw.$$

This yields the two integrals
$$A = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(w+u(1-w))^{n+1}}{(w(1-w))^{n+1}} w 
\frac{1-2w}{w+u(1-w)} \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(w+u(1-w))^{n}}{w^n (1-w)^{n+1}} (-w+(1-w))\;dw 
\\ = - \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(w+u(1-w))^{n}}{w^{n-1} (1-w)^{n+1}} \; dw
\\ + \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(w+u(1-w))^{n}}{w^n (1-w)^{n}} \; dw.$$

and
$$B = -\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(w+u(1-w))^{n+1}}{(w(1-w))^{n+1}} w 
\frac{w(1-w)}{(w+u(1-w))^2} (1-u) \; dw
\\ = - (1-u)\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(w+u(1-w))^{n-1}}{w^{n-1} (1-w)^{n}} \; dw.$$

We extract  the coeffcient  in $u$ first.  The integral $A$  gives two
pieces
$$-{n\choose q}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{w^{n-q}(1-w)^q}{w^{n-1} (1-w)^{n+1}} \; dw
\\ = -{n\choose q}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{w^{q-1} (1-w)^{n-q+1}} \; dw
= -{n\choose q} {n-2\choose n-q}$$

and
$${n\choose q}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{w^{n-q}(1-w)^q}{w^{n} (1-w)^{n}} \; dw
\\ = {n\choose q}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{w^{q} (1-w)^{n-q}} \; dw
= {n\choose q} {n-2\choose n-q-1}.$$

The integral in $B$ also gives two pieces
$$-{n-1\choose q} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{w^{n-1-q} (1-w)^{q}}{w^{n-1} (1-w)^{n}} \; dw
\\ = -{n-1\choose q} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{w^{q} (1-w)^{n-q}} \; dw
= -{n-1\choose q} {n-2\choose n-q-1}.$$

and
$${n-1\choose q-1} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{w^{n-q} (1-w)^{q-1}}{w^{n-1} (1-w)^{n}} \; dw
\\ = {n-1\choose q-1} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{w^{q-1} (1-w)^{n-q+1}} \; dw
= {n-1\choose q-1} {n-2\choose n-q}.$$

This yields the following answer before simplification:
$${n\choose q} {n-2\choose n-q-1}-{n\choose q} {n-2\choose n-q}
+ {n-1\choose q-1} {n-2\choose n-q}
- {n-1\choose q} {n-2\choose n-q-1}.$$

This simplifies to
$${n\choose q} {n-2\choose n-q}
\left(\frac{n-q}{q-1} - 1 
+ \frac{q}{n}
- \frac{n-q}{n} \frac{n-q}{q-1}\right)
\\ = {n\choose q} {n-2\choose n-q}
\frac{n-q}{n} \frac{1}{q-1}
= \frac{1}{q-1} {n-1\choose q} {n-2\choose n-q}
\\ = \frac{1}{n-1} {n-1\choose q} {n-1\choose n-q}.$$

The  generating  function  $T_n(u)$  can  be  verified  using  Maple's
**combstruct** package. This is the code.

```
with(combstruct);

gf_cs :=
proc(n)
    option remember;
    local trees, leaves;

    trees := { T=Union(Prod(Z, U),
                       Prod(Z, Sequence(T, 1<= card))),
               Z=Atom, U=Epsilon };

    leaves :=
    proc(struct)
        if type(struct, function) then
            return add(leaves(op(q, struct)), q=1..nops(struct));
        fi;

        if struct = Z then return 0 fi;
        return 1;
    end;

    add(u^leaves(t), t in allstructs([T, trees], size=n));
end;

CF := (n,q) -> 1/(n-1)*binomial(n-1,q)*binomial(n-1,n-q);

gf_verif := n -> add(CF(n,q)*u^q, q=1..n-1);
```

This will produce e.g. for $T_9(u)$ the generating function
$${u}^{8}+28\,{u}^{7}+196\,{u}^{6}+490\,{u}^{5}+490\,{u}^{4}
+196\,{u}^{3}+28\,{u}^{2}+u,$$

which matches the binomial coefficient formula.

**Addendum.**  We  show  that  the  counts  of  the  number  of  trees
classified according  the number of leaves  does indeed add  up to the
Catalan numbers in order to verify the above computation.

We have the sum
$$\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{q=1}^{n-1} {n-1\choose q} {n-1\choose n-q}.$$

We  can extend  this  to  include $q=0$  because  the second  binomial
coefficient is zero in that case:
$$\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose q} {n-1\choose n-q}.$$

Put $${n-1\choose n-q}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^{n-1}}{z^{n-q+1}} \; dz.$$

This yields for the sum
$$\frac{1}{n-1}\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^{n-1}}{z^{n+1}}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose q} z^q \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{n-1}\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^{n-1}}{z^{n+1}}
(1+z)^{n-1} \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{n-1}\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^{2n-2}}{z^{n+1}} \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{n-1}
{2n-2\choose n}.$$

This is
$$\frac{(2n-2)!}{n!\times (n-1)!}
= \frac{1}{n} {2n-2\choose n-1}.$$

We now recognize the [Catalan number](https://oeis.org/A000108) 
formula shifted by one, obtaining
$$ 1, 2, 5, 14, 42, 132, 429, 1430, 4862, 16796, 58786, \ldots $$
from $n=2$ on.

**Addendum.** The above admits radical simplification, wich can be found at this [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3108340/).

Answer (score 1):

Your thinking looks fairly sound there. All I can think of is the following complicated recurrence from looking at the leftmost sub-tree and enumerating over all possible values for its nodes and its leaves:

$$L_{n, k} = \sum_{i=1}^{n - 1}\prod_{j=1}^{max(k, i)}L_{i, j}L_{n - i, k - j} = \sum_{i=1}^{k}\prod_{j=1}^{i}L_{i, j}L_{n - i, k - j} + \sum_{i = k + 1}^{n - 1}\prod_{j=1}^{k}L_{i, j}L_{n - i, k - j}$$

where $L_{i, j}$ denotes the number of trees with $i$ nodes and $j$ leaves.